# How to do lazy loading of network HTTP request or block and re-initiate when required in Firefox Extension?

Tags: javascript, http, firefox, firefox-addon

I am working on a project in that we are prioritizing HTTP requests of resource loading. To achieve reordering of HTTP requests we need to either delay HTTP requests to send out or either cancel them and re-initiate them later.

Following code snippet can be used to cancel HTTP request in Firefox Extension.

```
observe: function(aSubject, aTopic, aData) {

  if (aTopic == 'http-on-modify-request') {

    .....

    aSubject.cancel(Components.results.NS_BINDING_ABORTED);

    ....

  }

}
```

But, Is there any way to delay (lazy loading of resources) HTTP request or re-initiate HTTP requests which were canceled during web page parsing by above code.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you cannot simply cancel requests and re-initiate them later. That looses the "binding" information, i.e. what request belongs to what document (or dependent resource). E.g. canceling an image request and re-initiating it later will not automatically tell the document (loader) that the request belongs to a certain image element. Please also note that there are background requests not initiated from document loading and have no document/window attached, like update pings or other add-ons doing API requests or downloading some files (just mentioning this because a lot of people forget about it when writing code dealing with http requests at such a low level).

There are two ways I can think of that might work for you:

1. [Use `nsISupportsPriority` with channels and/or load groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Changing_the_Priority_of_HTTP_Requests). This is what the http connection scheduler uses internally. It is possible though that another piece of code (Firefox document loader, other add-ons) uses this API after you call it and reverses your setting. You'll need account for this in your implementation.
2. You can use `nsIRequest.suspend()`/`.resume()`, but this *may* cause the connection, if any, to be dropped in the meantime, which might cause problems with web-apps that issue links that are only valid to access once. And IIRC there are some buggy scenarios that will confuse the connection scheduler (but I can't remember any bug numbers ATM).

For certain request types, it might be feasible to cancel and re-initiate, though. E.g. you can cancel an image request and use the same mechanism that is driving the ["Reload Image" menu item](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/366b5c0c02d3/browser/base/content/nsContextMenu.js#l987). That won't work (properly or at all) with document requests, script requests, etc.